# Returning a status code not found in HttpStatusCode enumeration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, error-handling

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I need to return a status code of 420, which is not found among the HttpStatusCode enumeration values.

Usually it's simple, you do something like:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
```

But what do I do when I don't have an enumeration value for the status code I want?

Comment: where you want to return the error in an attribute, filter, action, api acction?

Comment: This is in a method that returns an HttpResponseMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. All you have to do is cast the integer status code to HttpStatusCode:

```
return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode) 420, error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(420,"My message");
```

More reference on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Daniele, but in my case I need to return something derived from HttpResponseMessage rather than ActionResult. Sorry if that wasn't clear from my question.